# How can I update from select other table?

Tags: sql-server, select, subquery, sql-update, insert-update

i need update fields 'ErrCode' from select between 2 table. i try query it's update all record.

**Table LeaveEmp**

```
EmpRun Date                      Start                    Stop
00003  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 13:00:00.000  2012-10-02 17:00:00.000
00004  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   NULL                     NULL
```

**Table modifyTime**

```
EmpNo  cDate                     cIn                      cOut                      ErrCode
00001  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   NULL                     NULL                      NULL
00002  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 07:35:00.000  2012-10-02 20:12:00.000   NULL
00003  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 13:00:00.000  2012-10-02 17:00:00.000   NULL 
00004  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   NULL                     NULL                      NULL
00005  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 07:13:00.000  2012-10-02 19:24:00.000   NULL
00006  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 07:55:00.000  2012-10-02 20:58:00.000   NULL
*****00003,00004 from Table LeaveEmp.step one i insert Table LeaveEmp to Table modifyTime**
```

**code:**

```
UPDATE modifyTime
SET ErrCode = '3'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT coalesce(l.Start,'2012-10-02')
FROM LeaveEmp l
WHERE l.Start = '2012-10-02' and modifyTime.cDate = '2012-10-02')
```

**this get output:**

```
EmpNo  cDate                     cIn                      cOut                      ErrCode
00001  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   NULL                     NULL                      3
00002  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 07:35:00.000  2012-10-02 20:12:00.000   3
00003  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 13:00:00.000  2012-10-02 17:00:00.000   3 
00004  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   NULL                     NULL                      3
00005  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 07:13:00.000  2012-10-02 19:24:00.000   3
00006  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 07:55:00.000  2012-10-02 20:58:00.000   3
```

**but i need output:**

```
EmpNo  cDate                     cIn                      cOut                      ErrCode
00001  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   NULL                     NULL                      NULL
00002  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 07:35:00.000  2012-10-02 20:12:00.000   NULL
00003  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 13:00:00.000  2012-10-02 17:00:00.000   3 
00004  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   NULL                     NULL                      3
00005  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 07:13:00.000  2012-10-02 19:24:00.000   NULL
00006  2012-10-02 00:00:00.000   2012-10-02 07:55:00.000  2012-10-02 20:58:00.000   NULL
```

i need update from Table LeaveEmp only.

Thanks you fou your time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a link between modifyTime and LeaveEmp... try this

```
UPDATE modifyTime
SET ErrCode = '3'
FROM modifyTime m
INNER JOIN LeaveEmp l
  ON m.EmpNo = l.EmpRun
WHERE l.Start = '2012-10-02' and modifyTime.cDate = '2012-10-02'
```